# Subtract month from yearmonth

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL I have a criteria to subtract one month from the YYYYMM value. Kindly help me. I able to get answer with below

```
select 201608 - 1;
```

But when it is 01 month, It doesn't works.

Help me on this, without checking 01 month in if condition !

I also went through DATADD and DATEDIFF functions, but couldn't able to get results as expected

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL or SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Comment: that's not  "yearmonth". that's an integer. you can't expect whatever DB you're using to be  smart and recognize what that is. YOU have to tell the db it's a date/time value. until you do that, all you'er doing is provinding two regular numbers which the db will happily perform standard arithmetic on.

Comment: Iam Using SQL Server, Mistakenly chosen Postgre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select DateAdd(MM,-1,cast(cast(201608 as varchar(10))+'01' as date))
```

Returns a date of 2016-07-01

Comment: @CIPHER Do you want it back as an int 201607?

Comment: @Cappelletti - I got the answer with help of your suggestions, Thanks a ton

`Select substring(convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(MM,-1,cast(cast(201608 as varchar(10))+'01' as date)),112),1,6)`

Comment: @CIPHER Well done  You could exclude the substring  via CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateAdd(MM,-1,cast(cast(201608 as varchar(10))+'01' as date)), 112))/100

Answer (score 0):

SQL contains date manipulation functions. Use those:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, @dateToCheck), GETDATE())`

Comment: This is a T-SQL example - you tagged your question with both MS SQL and Postgres which uses different syntax

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use some math to convert int into base 12 int , substract month and return back to original encoding.

```
select d, m, res=(dd/12)*100 + dd%12 + 1
from (
  select *, (d/100)*12 + d%100  - 1 - m as dd
  from ( --sample data, m = months to substract
     values 
      (201608, 10), (201608, 2), (201601, 1), (201601, 12)
    ) t(d,m) 
  ) t
```